# How to Import Meta Tags More Easier Without Import XML

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have imported data for the title tag and meta description in Google Sheets using =IMPORTXML, but that method takes too long to load.

Is there another way to generate title tags and meta descriptions with hundreds of URLs for more easily in Google Sheets?

Thanks!

I've been using IMPORTXML but it's still hard to get data more easily for hundreds of URls.

Comment: In your situation, how about using Google Apps Script? When Google Apps Script is used, the URLs can be requested with the asynchronous process. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchallrequests) But, I'm not sure about your actual situation. So, I cannot propose clearly whether this approach can be used. I apologize for this.